# Which Ibatis version is compatible with Spring 4.1.9.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, ibatis

Which `Ibatis` version is compatible with `Spring v4.1.9.RELEASE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latest stable version for IBatis is v2.3.4.726.
Spring v4.1.9.Release do support this version.

Edited my answer

Comment: I don't see any released version for Ibatis above v2.3.4.726. I do see only beta versions.

Comment: Yes, that's why I mentioned Latest "Stable" version is v2.3.4.726